# Does --production work in npm install <tarball file>?

Tags: npm, npm-install

I used this command:

```
npm install xxxx.tgz --production --prefix xxxDirectory/
```

But the result folder node_modules contains the devDependencies.
Does the --production work in npm install ?

Comment: Check your package.json, every dependency that is on dependencies section will be loaded on production no matter if you think is a dev dependency. For that, you have to make sure that you put your dev dependencies on "devDependencies" section.

Answer (score 0):

In my testing, it doesn't seem like it. I haven't found it mentioned anywhere online, however.